# Were the Korrealis Prince and Korrealis Sovereign speeders Bind on Pickup or Bind on Equip?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Were the [Korrealis Prince and Sovereign speeders](http://dulfy.net/2012/05/29/complete-high-res-catalog-of-all-swtor-speeders/#20) BoP or BoE?  I ask because, my character having been poor at the time they were discontinued, I'm interested in buying them from someone now.  I've managed to get one of the two non-faction-specific Korrealis speeders, and have seen the other one listed on the GTN, so they were obviously BoE.  I haven't seen the faction-specific speeders listed though, and couldn't find any info about how they bind; hence, my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with Korrealis and Prince is they were PVP speeders. They required Rank 65 Valor to purchase and use them (I grinded up my PVP all of March for that). Despite them saying the requirements and binding would be removed on Korrealis Speeders, the PVP were exempt from that.

They didn't clarify (though, apparently some posts said only "some" Korrealis speeders would do this despite all being removed) very well so many users had bought up several. In fact, I still have 3 rotting in my bank that are for friends that I have never been able to give them (Similarly, one of them had gotten me a Prince in return).

Because they were PVP and had Valor requires, they were BoP. I've heard mixed things from staff including that it could be a bug (Since what sense does it make it only make half of them tradeable?) or that it was intentional. I was told to make a [suggestion thread](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=457795), but it kind of just blew up...

Comment: That makes more sense.  Hmm, hopefully we can convince BioWare to at least let all the extra ones be sold.

Answer (score 1):

Both Korrealis Prince and Sovereign speeders are BoP:

- [Prince](http://db.darthhater.com/items/38363/korrealis_prince/)
- [Sovereign](http://db.darthhater.com/items/9924/korrealis_sovereign/)

Comment: Hmm, Torhead says this same.  Looks to be the answer, unless it was one of those situations where they made it BoE for everyone who already had them so they could sell them off.  Anyways, thanks!